# Alias with query string

Tags: urls

Using Sitecore aliases, I want to go the a page with a query string. For example I want to go to `test/myOriginalPage?query=myQuery` using an alias `/myAlias`.

The only fields I could set are **"Path"** (name of the alias) and **"Target"** (target page I want to go).

Typing `test/myAlias` lets me go to `test/myOriginalPage` which is okay, but I need to also have the query string `?query=myQuery`.

Is there a way to add query strings as well? Or do I need to modify the code?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do this with an ootb alias and customizing that code just for a querystring seems a bit overkill. Why not use redirects?

There is a redirect module on the marketplace (https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/3/301_Redirect_module.aspx?sc_lang=en) that can help. This one can redirect to an item or a url, which can include a querystring.